# How to make a relation between two posts

Tags: custom-post-types

I'have this structure:

- **News** (CPT. A page showing all news)
- **Works** (CPT. A page showing all works)

Then, inside a single page of **works** I want to show the news related to this work:

- Single work

  - title
  - content
  - news related to this single work

How can I make a relation between a single post in **News** and single post in **Works**?

AFAIK, I can create a category term with same name of each single work, by hand, and then to assign that term to News single post. But there is high risk of typos and a lot of work in the content editor. Is it possible to get a more automated method?

Thank you.

Comment: Tags are your best friends here. That's one of the reasons they exist.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, I should to create, by hand, in each single News post, a tag for each work post, with the same name of each Work post and then, to do a query inside single work template using the work title as tag criterion. Is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the relations manually. WordPress is not smart enough to relate to posts by tags if you don't set them yourself ( It can however use categories, but not really efficient ).

What you can do, is to set some tags on a `News` post, and then use them to search the tags in `Works` posts. Here is an example:

```
get_related_posts($id){
    // Get current post's tags
    $tags = wp_get_post_tags($id);
    // Check if the post has any tags
    if ($tags) {
        // If it does, get them and make a query based on tags
        $tag_ids = array();
        foreach($tags as $individual_tag) {
            $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;
        }
        $args = array(
            'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
            'post__not_in' => array($id),
            'posts_per_page'=>8, 
            'ignore_sticky_posts'=> 1,
            'post_type' => 'works'
        );
        $related_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        // Starting the loop
        if ( $related_query->have_posts()) {
            while ($related_query->have_posts()){
            $related_query->the_post();
                the_title();
            }
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Feed this function with a post ID and you will get a list of related posts in the `Works` post type that have the same tags as this post:

```
get_related_posts(get_the_ID());
```

You can do a conditional to use the same function for both post types.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Advance custom fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) plugin for this. Select a field group for CPT **works** and use field type "Relationship" with CPT **news**. It will provide UI in the admin panel to select one from available news.

Comment: Let me know if you need any help on this from me. Accept the answer if helps you to achieve your goal.

Comment: Sorry, relational field needs a pro license for the plugin :( Jack's answer works without plugin and I can't accept two answers. Nex time! :)